# Peazip Text Compression

Tags: compression

I need windows commands/script to compress multiple files in a single folder.

I see only few commandsaa are available.

Can anyone forward the basics zip and unzip commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is the on line guide for Peazip commands, from its domain: http://www.peazip.org/peazip-command-line.html

As for what I recall, you can also work as usual with Peazip and then export what you are doing as a script, from "Console" tab. Then you can edit/reuse the script at will.